# Как разместить ImageView поверх LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

У меня проблема, не могу разместить ImageView(синенький логотип) на передний план, а linearLayout(в которому находится ImageView) на задний план.
Как это можно сделать?

Вот так приложение выглядит на данный момент

[image: Вот так приложение выглядит на данный момент]

А вот так должно выглядеть

[image: А вот так должно выглядеть]

код xml прикрепляю ниже:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inchat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cookie_regular"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/main_color"
        android:text="Hello world" />


    <!-- content goes here -->

    <!-- stretching frame layout, using layout_weight -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- your bottom content -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Comment: Из описания не очень ясно что вам нужно. Попробуйте нарисовать что хотите получить и приложите разметку экрана текстом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Извините, уже исправил

Comment: Правильным тут будет использование ConstraintLayout - сможете картинку расположить над контейнером с кнопками. RelativeLayout вообще в настоящее время никто не использует.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб К сожалению замена на ConstraintLayout не помогла.
Мне не нужно размещать картинку над контейнером с кнопками, мне нужно лишь чтобы картинка на 50% выходила из контейнера с кнопками(50% картинки в контейнере, 50% за контейнером)

Comment: Надо не заменять, а полностью переписать всю разметку внутри ScrollView, заменив главный LinearLayout на ConstraintLayout. Картинку убрать из внутреннего LinearLayout и поместить специальным образом над верхом внуреннего LinearLayout через constraintTopToTopOf="ТУТ ID внутреннего линеара" и constraintBottomToBottomOf="ТУТ ID внутреннего линеара"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо большое, вы мн очень помогли.
И так мне на будущее, предпочтительнее использовать ConstraintLayout, чем RelativeLayout и LinearLayour?

Comment: Пожалуйста) Да, для чего-то крупнее чем текстовое поле с картинкой предпочтительно использовать ConstraintLayout. RelativeLayout не следует вообще использовать. LinearLayour подойдёт для простейших элементов и только если их немного.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот эту разметку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECEC"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloWorld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/helloWorld">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:paddingBottom="75dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:text="Button1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:text="Button1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/dialog_content"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```